# Integrar mercado pago con php

Tags: php, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Estoy tranado de integrar mercado pago con PHP ya van varias veces que recibo este error al querer elegir las cuotas :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Quisiera saber donde se obtiene el payments_id: (:id)
'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/:id?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_ENV'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo encuentras en la **respuesta** que devuelve MercadoPago cuando haces un pago.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]